# How to convert a string into a hyperlink in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, string, hyperlink

I am getting a string from an API. I use a JSON library to parse it, and after I put the string into a UITextView, I need to convert it into a hyperlink. When the user clicks on that hyperlink it should open Safari and load that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as

```
 yourTextView.editable = NO;
 yourTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Please follow [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html) for more detail.

This will detect links automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` has the **property** `dataDetectorTypes` to show the the link as highlighted real link.

```
@property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes
```

Set `dataDetectorTypes` with `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`.

**Use it as below**

```
 myTextView.editable = NO;
 myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

**From Documentation for dataDetectorTypes of [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html)**

> You can use this property to specify
>   the types of data (phone numbers, http
>   links, and so on) that should be
>   automatically converted to clickable
>   URLs in the text view. When clicked,
>   the text view opens the application
>   responsible for handling the URL type
>   and passes it the URL.

Answer (score 0):

textFiled.editable =NO;
textfield.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

DONT MISS @property, @ synthsize

@property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes

@synthesize dataDetectorTypes;

Comment: This answer is very confusing. Can you please explain what each of the things you posted does and where to put them?